# DataReader best-practices

Tags: datareader

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545500/ado-net-what-is-best-practice-for-getting-datareader-values), but the answers never really got around to what I want to know.  Is there any standards around getting values from a DataReader?  I.e., is this

```
dataReader.GetString(dataReader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName"));
```

considered better/worse/the same as this?

```
(string) dataReader["ColumnName"];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the way that I do it:

```
Int32 ordinal = dataReader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName");

if (!dataReader.IsDBNull(ordinal))
    yourString = dataReader.GetString(ordinal);
```

It is important to check for `DBNull` like I have shown above because if the field is null in the `DataReader` it will throw an exception when you try to retrieve it.

Comment: Absolutely agreed.  I'm asking more about the syntactical differences of getting the actual value, using the DataReaders Item[] functionality vs. using the provided DataReader.Get<type value> methods.

Comment: Since the `datareader["column"]` format returns an object and is not strongly-typed, I don't think you'll get an exception right then if the data is `DbNull`. You'll just get `DbNull.Value` cast to `object`. Of course, you may get an exception later when you try to use the value if you don't first do a `Convert.IsDbNull` check.

Answer (score 9):

I made some extension methods to let me treat an `IDataReader` as an enumerable, and to deal with `DbNull` by returning nullable ints, etc. This lets me check for null and apply a default value with the C# `??` operator.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns an IEnumerable view of the data reader.
/// WARNING: Does not support readers with multiple result sets.
/// The reader will be closed after the first result set is read.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<IDataRecord> AsEnumerable(this IDataReader reader)
{
    if (reader == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");

    using (reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return reader;
        }
    }
}

public static int? GetNullableInt32(this IDataRecord dr, string fieldName)
{
    return GetNullableInt32(dr, dr.GetOrdinal(fieldName));
}

public static int? GetNullableInt32(this IDataRecord dr, int ordinal)
{
    return dr.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : (int?)dr.GetInt32(ordinal);
}
```

...and so on for the other `GetDataType()` methods on `IDataReader`.

Comment: Well, you could if `IDataReader` had anything at all to do with `IEnumerable`. However, this is not the case. The signature is: `public interface IDataReader : IDisposable, IDataRecord`

Comment: Nice, but you might want to close the reader after the: `while (reader.Read())` loop

Comment: Hmm, does the reader really get closed from that Using? I thought the using would only close the reader, if you initialize the reader in it like: using (var reader = new DataReader){...} Am I wrong?

Comment: @SwissCoder - The `using` statement only requires that you pass in an `IDisposable` instance. It doesn't require that you create the instance inside the parens.

Comment: thank you Joel for taking the time, learnt something today :)

Comment: @JoelMueller, `DbDataReader` implements `IEnumerable`, and it will be rare someone has a concrete ADO.NET implementation of `IDataReader` without inheriting from `DbDataReader`. So basically this should work: `((DbDataReader)reader).Cast<IDataRecord>()`. Just saying..

Answer (score 0):

This an extension class; it works pretty ok for me. It handles nulls for int and boolean:

```
   public static class Utility
        {
            public static string ValidatorDataReaderString(this SqlDataReader pSqlDataReader, string pCampo)
            {
                var wValorReader = pSqlDataReader[pCampo];
                if (wValorReader != null)
                {
                    string wValorRetorno = Convert.ToString(pSqlDataReader[pCampo]);
                    return _ = wValorRetorno == string.Empty ? null : wValorRetorno;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    
            public static int ValidatorDataReaderInt(this SqlDataReader pSqlDataReader, string pCampo)
            {
                var wValorReader = pSqlDataReader[pCampo];
                if (wValorReader != null)
                {
                    bool wValorParse = int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(pSqlDataReader[pCampo]), out int oValorRetorno);
                    return wValorParse ? oValorRetorno : 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
    
            public static bool ValidatorDataReaderBool(this SqlDataReader pSqlDataReader, string pCampo)
            {
                if (pSqlDataReader[pCampo] != null)
                {
                    var wValor = Convert.ToString(pSqlDataReader[pCampo]);
    
                    if (wValor == "1" || wValor == "True")
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```